# How to use touch listeners and play a sound only when touching a button?

Tags: java, android, button, touch

I have an app with a button which plays a sound when clicked and pauses when clicked again. Now I want this button to only play sound when the button is touched and pause when the touch releases. What I mean is: I touch and hold it the song plays, I untouch it and the song stops playing.So the song should only play when the user touches and holds it not when the button is untouched. I even want a custom button(image) to show as long as the touch state is true and as soon as I untouch it, the default custom button is shown.
Here is the code to my main activity:

```
package com.example.firozkaoo2222.myapplication;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static com.example.firozkaoo2222.myapplication.R.raw.police;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private MediaPlayer policeSound;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button policeSounds = this.findViewById(R.id.police);

    policeSounds.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int eventPadTouch = event.getAction();

            switch (eventPadTouch) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // start playing sound , in your case:
                    policeSound.start();
                    return true;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // stop playing sound , in your case:
                    policeSound.stop();
                    return true;

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}}
```

Code for my custom button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />


</selector>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this snippet instead of your `OnClickListener` method:

```
policeSounds.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (policeSound == null) {
            policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.police);
        }

        int eventPadTouch = event.getAction();

        switch (eventPadTouch) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // start playing sound , in your case:
                policeSound.start();
                return true;


            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // stop playing sound , in your case:
                policeSound.pause();
                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please guide me exactly where I should put this code. I'm just a beginner

Comment: The app runs without any issue but when I touch the button the app closes.

Comment: just add `if (policeSound == null) {
            policeSound = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.police);
        }`

Comment: Awesome! Its working now. Just the button isn't changing.

Comment: It seems it's not related to java side, I think your xml file has some bugs

Comment: No worries! I'll try ti fix em .The main part is solved. .Thank you :)

Comment: Really sorry! I'm new to stack overflow. Didn't knew that tick was for that purpose :p

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your `onCreate()` method:

```
policeSounds.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){ //The id check can be ignored since the listener is on the button already
            //play your sound
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){ //The id check can be ignored since the listener is on the button already
            //stop the sound
        }
        return true; //you need to return `true` otherwise it won't work
    }
});
```

Comment: The app runs and upon pressing the button nothing actually happens. Remains stationary , button doesn't work.

Comment: It is still the same.Idk whats the issue

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use setOnTouchListener not setOnClickListener, and play the sound if event action is ACTION_DOWN (button is being pressed) and stop the sound when the event action is ACTION_UP (touch is released) :

```
yourButton.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            play();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            stop();
            break;

    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I got this concept ! Thanks :)